# Copy 1 file from multiple subdirectories to another directory

Tags: parsing, batch-file, copy, subdirectory, enumerate

I've searched Google and forums for days trying to figure out how to accomplish building a batch file that will parse a directory tree and copy 1 file from each subdirectory to a new folder.

I've got this as a lead:
http://www.pcreview.co.uk/forums/can-copy-file-multiple-folders-t1959548.html

and this...
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1...in-a-directory

And I've tried this:

```
@ECHO OFF
CLS
PAUSE
FOR /R %%A in (C:\Users\Liam\Desktop\Master) DO (   
COPY %%A  C:\Users\Liam\Desktop\Master\Master-Copies\
GOTO :Exit
)
:Exit
Pause
```

The pauses are present because I'm trying to figure out exactly what is occurring.

Within my "Master" directory there are about 250 subdirectories. I'd like to copy a single file from each subdirectory and put them in a new subdirectory called "Master-Copies", which should ultimately have 250 files. The subdirectories and files don't have spaces in their names, however I'd like to build that functionality into the batch file in case I ever run into this situation again. I'd like to copy the first file in each subdirectory. I know from reading other forums that the "FIRST" file is relative, but I'd like it to be the first file sorted by name.

I know I'm asking a lot, and hopefully some genius here can help out a kid new to programming.

Answer (score 1):

Problem 1 - you are miss-using the /R option. The root directory should follow the /R option, and the file filter should appear in the IN() clause. Read the FOR help by typing `FOR /?` from the command line.

Problem 2 - your loop will abort after the first GOTO, so at most you would copy a file from one directory.

Problem 3 - you need to skip your destination directory since it is a subdirectory of your root.

Solution: You will need 2 loops, the first to walk the directory hierarchy starting at your root, and a 2nd loop to list the files in a single directory. You will need to EXIT /B or GOTO out of the 2nd loop after copying the 1st file, but this will not work if the 2nd loop is embedded within the 1st loop - the exit/goto would exit out of the outer most loop.

To get around the problem you need to have the 1st loop call a subroutine that contains the 2nd loop. You can then EXIT /B from the 2nd loop and it will return to your 1st loop and pick up where it left off. Only call the subroutine if the directory does not match your destination directory.

```
@echo off
setlocal
set root="C:\Users\Liam\Desktop\Master"
set dest="C:\Users\Liam\Desktop\Master\Master-Copies\"
for /r /d %root% %%D in (*) do if "%%D" neq %dest% call :copyFirstFile "%%D"
pause
exit /b

:copyFirstFile
for %%F in ("%~1\*") do (
  copy "%%F" %dest%
  exit /b
)
```

Comment: Thank you dbenham!  Any chance you can take a stab at the new question below regarding files being overwritten?

Comment: @user1205701 If this answer helped you, you should accept and give it an upvote.